# ResultSet não está posicionado corretamente, talvez você precise chamar next

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web utilizando JSP e Servlet e que cadastro os dados dos produtos no banco de dados e apresento os dados em uma table, mas ao tentar ver a imagem cadastrada pela chave primaria a descricao `http://localhost:8080/EccomerceJSP2/produto/imagens?descricao=effefetu` ele apresenta o erro.

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet não está posicionado corretamente, talvez você precise chamar next.

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet não está posicionado corretamente, talvez você precise chamar next.
Model.ProdutosDAO.lerImagem(ProdutosDAO.java:108)
Controler.ImagemProdutosServlet.doGet(ImagemProdutosServlet.java:72)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
  root cause

  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet não está posicionado 
  corretamente, talvez você precise chamar next.
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkResultSet(PgResultSet.java:2770)
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:1893)
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:2478)
Model.ProdutosDAO.lerImagemRetorno(ProdutosDAO.java:62)
Model.ProdutosDAO.lerImagem(ProdutosDAO.java:105)
Controler.ImagemProdutosServlet.doGet(ImagemProdutosServlet.java:72)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

ProdutosDAO

```
Connection con;
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement pst;

 private static final String LISTAR_SQL = "SELECT prod_cod, prod_nome, prod_desc, prod_valor, prod_marca, prod_tamanho,prod_tecido, prod_imagem ,prod_tipo_imagem FROM tb_produtos";

private static final String POR_ID_SQL = "SELECT prod_cod, prod_nome, prod_desc, prod_valor, prod_marca, prod_tamanho, prod_parcela, prod_tecido FROM tb_produtos WHERE prod_desc = ?";

private static final String IMAGEM_SQL = "SELECT prod_tipo_imagem, prod_imagem FROM tb_produtos WHERE prod_desc = ?";

private static final String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO tb_produtos (prod_nome, prod_desc, prod_valor, prod_marca, prod_tamanho, prod_tecido, prod_imagem ,prod_tipo_imagem) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

private static final ProdutosDAO singleton = new ProdutosDAO();//criar objetos únicos para os quais há apenas uma instância. Este padrão oferece um ponto de acesso global, assim como uma variável global, porém sem as desvantagens das variáveis globais.

public ProdutosDAO() {
}


 public static ProdutosDAO instancia() {
     return singleton;
}

private Produtos lerProduto(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    int codigo = rs.getInt("prod_cod");
     String nome = rs.getString("prod_nome");
    String descricao = rs.getString("prod_desc");
    double valor = rs.getDouble("prod_valor");
    String marca = rs.getString("prod_marca");
    String tamanho = rs.getString("prod_tamanho");
    //int parcelas = rs.getInt("prod_parcela");
    String tecido = rs.getString("prod_tecido");
    //String tipo = rs.getString("tipo");
    return new Produtos(codigo,nome, descricao, valor, marca, tamanho, tecido);
}



private ImagemProdutos lerImagemRetorno(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

    String tipo = rs.getString("prod_tipo_imagem");
    byte[] conteudo = rs.getBytes("prod_imagem");
    return new ImagemProdutos(tipo, conteudo);
}

public List<Produtos> listarTodos() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try (
        Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(LISTAR_SQL);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    ) {
        List<Produtos> lista = new ArrayList<>(); 
        while (rs.next()) {
            lista.add(lerProduto(rs));
        }
        return lista;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


public Produtos lerProduto(String descricao) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try (
        Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(POR_ID_SQL);
    ) {
        ps.setString(1, descricao);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            return lerProduto(rs);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public ImagemProdutos lerImagem(String descricao) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try (
        Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(IMAGEM_SQL);
    ) {
        ps.setString(1, descricao);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            return lerImagemRetorno(rs);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


 public void salvar(Produtos pro, ImagemProdutos im) {
    try (
        Connection con = Conecta.conexao();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
    ) {

        ps.setString(1, pro.getNome());
        ps.setString(2, pro.getDescricao());
        ps.setDouble(3, pro.getValor());
        ps.setString(4, pro.getMarca());
        ps.setString(5, pro.getTamanho());
        ps.setString(6, pro.getTecido());
        ps.setBytes(7, im.getConteudo());
        ps.setString(8, im.getFormato());


        ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(ProdutosDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

Servlet responsavel pelo cadastro

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    int codigo = 0;

    String nome = request.getParameter("nome");

   // do {
     //   codigo++;

   // } while (nome != null);


String descricao = request.getParameter("descricao");
double valor = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("valor"));
String marca = request.getParameter("marca");
String tamanho = request.getParameter("tamanho");

String tecido = request.getParameter("tecido");

Part imagePart = request.getPart("file");
String tipo = getFileType(imagePart);
byte[] conteudo = imagePart == null ? new byte[0] : getBytesFromInputStream(imagePart.getInputStream());

Produtos p = new Produtos(codigo, nome, descricao, valor, marca, tamanho, tecido);
ImagemProdutos im = new ImagemProdutos(tipo, conteudo);

ProdutosDAO.instancia ()
.salvar(p, im);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/produtos/listar");

dispatcher.forward (request, response);

 }

 private String getFileType(Part part) {
    if (part == null) return "";
    String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    for (String content : partHeader.split(";")) {
        String trimmedContent = content.trim();
        if (trimmedContent.startsWith("filename")) {
            String nomeEntreAspas = trimmedContent.substring(trimmedContent.indexOf('=') + 1);
            String nomeDoArquivo = nomeEntreAspas.trim().replace("\"", "");
            String extensao = nomeDoArquivo.substring(nomeDoArquivo.indexOf('.') + 1);
            return extensao;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    try {

         ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];

        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        return os.toByteArray();
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;

    }
```

Servlet responsavel por mostrar a imagem pela chave primaria descricao

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //a imagem deve ser eniada por url, em uma servlet separada propria

    try {
      String descricao= request.getParameter("descricao");
        Model.ImagemProdutos ip = ProdutosDAO.instancia().lerImagem(descricao);
        response.setContentType("image/" + ip.getFormato());
        response.getOutputStream().write(ip.getConteudo());



    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImagemProdutosServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

JSP

```
<h3>Lista de Produtos Cadastrados</h3>

      <table border="1">
      <tr>
          <th>Codigo</th> 
          <th>Produto</th>
           <th>Nome</th>
           <th>Descricao</th>
           <th>Valor</th>
           <th>Marca</th>
           <th>Tamanho</th>

          <th>Tecido</th>

      </tr>


      <c:forEach items="${requestScope.produtos}" var="registro">

          <tr>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.codigo}"/></td>
              <td> <img src="<c:url value="/produto/imagens?descricao=${registro.descricao}"/>"</td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.nome}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.descricao}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.valor}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.marca}"/></td>
              <td> <c:out value="${registro.tamanho}"/></td>

              <td> <c:out value="${registro.tecido}"/></td>

          </tr>


      </c:forEach>

  </table>
```

Comment: O `ResultSet` começa posicionado antes da primeira linha de resultados. Você deve invocar `rs.next()` antes de começar a ler os dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mensagem de erro está dizendo exatamente qual é o problema. Veja:

No método `lerImagem()` você faz:

```
try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
    return lerImagemRetorno(rs);
}
```

O no método `lerImagemRetorno()` você faz:

```
String tipo = rs.getString("prod_tipo_imagem");
byte[] conteudo = rs.getBytes("prod_imagem");
return new ImagemProdutos(tipo, conteudo);
```

Repare que em nenhum momento o método [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) de [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) é chamado.

---

Considerando que o ResultSet `rs` irá retornar sempre um resultado para esse caso, você pode fazer:

```
try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
    while(rs.next()) {
        return lerImagemRetorno(rs);
    }
}
```

Com tudo, para casos onde o ResultSet retorna mais do que um registro deve-se trabalhar com algum tipo de coleção ([`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) e etc).

Mas independente disso, o ponto principal é chamar o método `next()` pois ele move "a posição de leitura" do ResultSet para a próxima posição.

---

A documentação do método [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) começa com:

> *Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position*

Sendo que a documentação do retorno diz:

> ***Returns:** `true` if the new current row is valid; `false` if there are no more rows*

Ou seja, caso o método `next()` seja invocado porém não exista mais registros, o valor `false` é retornado.

É justamente por isso que colocamos a chamada desse método dentro de um `while`.